# Run stepping motor eficiently on battery

Tags: batteries, stepper-motor

I just bought `NEMA17` stepping motor with Rated voltage of 3.57V and 1.8A with A4988 driver board to control the motor from raspberry pi.
I'm looking for a easy way to supply energy to this motor, I was thinking about batteries, but the uncle Google says that stepping motors are electrically-inefficient. Does this apply even if I use the A4988 driver board? Also can I supply energy from two 9V batteries?

I also have a notebook adapter for 12V with plug at the end, but I don't want to destroy the plug to connect normal cables

*EDIT* : I want to move the motor from A to B (about 1 meter forward and 1 meter back) one time per hour.
There should be not outside force for the motor so I think I don't need to hold a torque.
Motor should move `car` like machine (with wheels) from A to B stopping every 10cm for like 30 seconds.
The project should be place outside, but I really don't except wind so strong to move the wheels, so hold a torque is not important

Comment: what kind of 9 V batteries?

Comment: Alkaline 9V duracell (looks like a cube)

Comment: What is the amp hour rating of that cube?

Comment: you could probably run an old pager vibration motor for a few minutes on that battery

Comment: How efficient should the system be? Stepper is crap, but when moving its pretty efficient.

Comment: I want it to move a belt long 2 meters forward and back every one hour or so. Should I rather use an adapter?

Comment: I don't know, not enough data. I am pretty sure you have questions because you don't have the data either. Draw the system, write down the requirements, and you will see what's missing.

Comment: @MarcelKopera Yes, use an adapter and search for "barrel connector to screw terminal adapter" to find an easy way to avoid altering your 12 V adapter's plug.

Comment: "*I want it to move a belt long 2 meters forward and back every one hour or so.*" That information belongs in your question along with telling us whether or not you need holding torque. Obviously if you can switch off the motor when motion is finished then energy requirements are greatly reduced. Add in a link to the 9 V batteries you were considering and quote their Ah rating. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: thanks for the comments, there should be no "outside force" so I really don't need to hold a torque <- I don't count wind, but I think its not so important for my project.

Comment: I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Desktop PC power supply will hopefully do it for you. You can often find a discarded computer waiting for pickup. Or you could buy one on Amazon, for pretty cheap, such as [this one for $20 USD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0081H7E4E). Just connecting the green wire with one of the black wires (they're all grounds) should turn on the power supply. And both the 5V output and the 12V output should deliver more than enough current to meet your needs. You will probably be disappointed with a battery solution.